# Angular 6: How to bind the formArray value on save event?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have a form with array values. Values are displaying in the form is perfectly but at the time of saving the value it is not binding the whole array values; instead of it is binding only last changed value.

Also, the `formControlName="id"` property value is not binding into formArray object.

[StackBlitz working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ht8ykn?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

App.component.ts

```
initializRecords(data?: any) {
  this.dataForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    dataCollection: this.formBuilder.group({
      id: new FormControl(),
      sizeId: new FormControl(),
      sizes: this.formBuilder.group({
        qty: new FormControl([])
      })
    })
  });
}
```

App.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="dataForm">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="saveRecords()">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div formArrayName="dataCollection">
      <div class="row" *ngFor="let element of data; let first = first">
        <div *ngIf="!first">----------</div>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let subElement of element.sizes">
          <div class="col">
            <mat-form-field class="">
              <input matInput type="text" formControlName="id" value={{element.value}} readonly>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="">
              <input matInput type="text" value={{subElement.subValue}} readonly>
              <input type="hidden" formControlName="sizeId">
            </mat-form-field>
            <div formGroupName="sizes">
              <mat-form-field class="">
                <input matInput type="text" formControlName="qty"  value={{subElement.qty}}>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

=== Updated ===

On click of save event I would like the final JSON like this below structure as the values are displayed per row.

```
{
  "data": [
  { "id": 1, "sizeId": 1, "qty": 10 },
  { "id": 1, "sizeId": 2, "qty": 1 },
  { "id": 1, "sizeId": 3, "qty": 1 },
  { "id": 2, "sizeId": 1, "qty": 50 },
  { "id": 2, "sizeId": 2, "qty": 60 },
  { "id": 2, "sizeId": 3, "qty": 70 },
]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your usage of form is not really good.

You have 2 different types of data, one which is 'Lorium' and the other one which is 'Ipsum'. I think you should first define an array on `dataCollection` where you create 2 differents `FormGroup`.

Then in each `FormGroup` you will have an array with all your sub elements.

I am not sure of what you need and try to do with you program, but this way, you will have all the quantities stored as well as you want.

I share you a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c2t9uz?file=src/app/app.component.ts) with this way of thinking. If you think I misunderstood something tell me.

Moreover, you can add any `FormControl` that you need on each `FormGroup` to fit the form with your json data.

Finally, if you want to fit you required JSON, just iterate over you elements to add them to an object.

Comment: Yes it is working almost similar as per my expected requirement. 

But at the end I need the response into same one array of object collection. 

I have updated the question about that sample json collection needed in the response, can you please review ?

Comment: @AJT81 I have edited the stackblitz, check if it works for you :)

Comment: Phew !!! It seems working fine. Let me integrate into my actual project. Thank you so much for your time and efforts. 
Cheers !!!